# Swift - Case statement and MetaType check?

Tags: swift

Given a dictionary I need to check to see if the value is Dictionary, Array, or Other.
I get the following error:

> Downcast pattern value of type Dictionary cannot be used

```
// Type of dictionary to enumerate through
public typealias SourceDictionary = [String: AnyObject]
var dictionary: SourceDictionary


for (key, value) in dictionary {
   switch (value) {
      case value as SourceDictionary :
         print("Dictionary")

      case value as Array :
         print("Array")

      default :
         print("Other")
   }
}
```

Also tried

```
case let someValue as SourceDictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with either a `switch` or an `if` statement, your syntax just isn't quite right.

Switch:

```
for (key, value) in dictionary {
    switch value {
    case let v as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>:
        println("Dictionary in \(key)")
    default:
        println("other")
    }
}
```

If:

```
for (key, value) in dictionary {
    if let v = value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        println("Dictionary in \(key)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this specific to generic types? If you look at the docs they have a sample that does something similar, but with Stirng, Int, etc. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html

Comment: Sorry, bad answer before -- you're just missing a little of the `switch` syntax.